# Как создать новый String в каждой итерации цикла?

Tags: java, строки

Бегу по листу зная что каждые 2 индекса в листе образуют HTTP метод + URL.

Пример:

```
list.get(0); //POST
list.get(1); //loan/test?testArg=1234&id=5555555
```

В итоге получается один string

```
POST/loan/test?testArg=1234&id=5555555
```

Вот код:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i+=2){
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + list.get(i+1));
    }
```

Теперь нужно при каждрой итерации создать отдельный string и положить туда нужные значения.

Comment: А чем не подходит определение массива строк и обращение к нему через итератор?

Comment: А какая разница, ведь в итоге мне нужно опеределенное кол-во string переменных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите создать несколько *именованных переменных*, то это невозможно. Переменные создаются во время написания кода, а не во время исполнения (я сознательно опускаю возможность вмешательства в байткод, не делайте так).

Если же речь идёт о создании *объектов* типа String, то можете хранить их в каком-либо контейнере, например списке:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i+=2){
        result.add(list.get(i) + list.get(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Да я имел в виду именнованных переменных. Но думаю что ваш вариант тоже подойдет. Спасибо